# How do I to receive a variable from Livewire in a Javascript script?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire Component in `app/Http/Livewire/Data.php`

```
class Data extends Component
{
    public $data= 0;

    public function data()
    {
        $this->data= 100;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.data');
    }
}
```

I have a view in `resorces/views/livewire/data.blade.php` I want to know how I can make use of the $data variable within a script found in this same view.

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <button wire:click="data"> My buttom</button>
    <-- Here its shown without problems -->
    <h1>{{ $data }}</h1>
</div>

<!-- Not shown here -->
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        var data = @this.data
        console.log(data) 
    })
</script>
```

It doesn't show me the value of `data` when I doing console.log ()

Answer (score 1):

Within your Blade file, you can simply set the variable in JavaScript:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <button wire:click="data"> My buttom</button>
    <-- Here its shown without problems -->
    <h1>{{ $data }}</h1>
</div>

<!-- Not shown here -->
<script>
var data = {{ $data }}
console.log(data) 
</script>
```

Comment: I did that, it didn't work either, the variable is generated after clicking, maybe it receives the value in the javascript but it doesn't update it

Comment: Is the script part of the blade file? If so, it should update. Also, your render method returns `view('livewire.counter');` while the file was named `resorces/views/livewire/data.blade.php`. Is this just a typo?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same blade file and it is a typo.

Comment: Can you see inspect the content on your site to see if the variable is printed out after `var data = ...`?

Comment: When I inspect... If I do mouseover I can't see the value of `console.log(data)` but when I refresh the browser with parameters... `www.myweb.com?lat=25.7758&lng=-80.3465`  I Can see it (The value of console.log(data),

Comment: Im thinking that I must create a listener, when the url parameters change... Get the information

Comment: I don't see a need for a listener. Printing out should be enough. I've just noticed you variable and your method have the same name. Try to give your method a different name, e.g. "setData".

Comment: I changed the method name for setData, and same. I tryed with Dispatching Browser Events and I received the information, but, I don't know if it is the correct way and if it consumes more resources.

Comment: `$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('name-updated', ['newName' => $value]);` and `<script> window.addEventListener('name-updated', event => { alert('Name updated to: ' + event.detail.newName); }) </script>`

Comment: The renamed method and directly outputting is the correct way. An eventListener is not needed as far as I can tell. Can you put the source code on GitHub?

Comment: Im sorry I was out. `https://github.com/alquialrium/livewire`

Comment: Is this the latest version? The method name is still the name, there isn't the recommended way to output the variable and the there is still a eventlistener

Comment: Without the listener it doesn't work, I updated the repository, it is working but I have doubts if it is recommended like this.